# Fail to handle csrf token in Jmeter (403)

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to capture csrf token and pass as a header in login request but encounter 403 error. I've checked the csrf token extracted from a previous request by using regex extractor and successfully passed as a header of login request. Do not know what the reasons why the login request is failed. Please kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check that you captured the value **fully**. Also [using regular expressions for extracting values from HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), maybe it worth considering switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://%201.%20Double%20check%20that%20you%20captured%20the%20value%20**fully**.%20Also%20using%20regular%20expressions%20for%20extracting%20values%20from%20HTML%20is%20not%20the%20best%20idea,%20maybe%20it%20worth%20considering%20switching%20to%20CSS%20Selector%20Extractor%20instead%20%202.%20It%20might%20be%20the%20case%20the%20token%20in%20the%20response%20is%20encoded%20somehow,%20i.e.%20%5BURL-encoded%5D%5B1%5D%20or%20contains%20%5BHTML%20escape%20characters%5D%5B2%5D%20or%20something%20like%20this%20so%20try%20using%20your%20%5Bbrowser%20developer%20tools%5D%5B3%5D%20to%20see%20the%20token%20in%20the%20response%20and%20in%20the%20header%20of%20the%20next%20request%20and%20compare%20them%20symbol-to-symbol%20%203.%20It%20might%20also%20be%20the%20case%20the%20CSRF%20token%20works%20fine%20and%20the%20problem%20is%20somewhere%20else,%20i.e.%20do%20you%20have%20%5BHTTP%20Cookie%20Manager%5D%5B4%5D%20added%20to%20your%20Test%20Plan%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/%20%20%20%5B3%5D:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools%20%20%20%5B4%5D:%20https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) instead
2. It might be the case the token in the response is encoded somehow, i.e. [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or contains [HTML escape characters](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/) or something like this so try using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see the token in the response and in the header of the next request and compare them symbol-to-symbol
3. It might also be the case the CSRF token works fine and the problem is somewhere else, i.e. do you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added to your Test Plan

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation. Much appreciated ! I will try all of these and keep you posted.